# bash / awk inner deletion

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I need a little advice/help with this bash line, which i'm trying to accomplish using awk,

Basically, i have a variable holding comma separated values, like so:

```
"abc,abd,abf,abz,abz"
```

Getting each field is very easy with a simple awk loop

```
echo ${var} | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'
```

The problem is that sometime these comma separated values contain a string, with comma in the middle, e.g:

```
"abc,"abd,abf,abz",abh,abr,alk"
```

In this case "abd,abf,abz" is a single value, i need to tell awk that whats between quotes has to be treated as whole value and not to be separated but i get nowhere,
Any advice?

Comment: is the variable always in the same column?

Comment: no, unfortunately not,

Comment: Since `awk` assumes that every occurrence of the field separator actually separates two fields, it's not really suitable for parsing a file where quoted field separators are not treated as such. Use a language that has a CSV parser to process your file; such a parser will already know how to handle quoted field separators properly.

Comment: it does not have to be achieved necessarily by using awk, i cant believe that such a simple text editing operation is not achievable with any unix tool

Comment: Is your text REALLY `"abc,...,alk"` or is it instead `abc,...,alk`? In other words do the initial and final double quote characters actually exist in your string or are you adding them above to show us that it's a string?

Comment: it is not always consistent, within double quotes the commas can be spread at any char position

Comment: That isn't related to the question I asked. I'm asking about the FIRST and LAST double quote in the example you posted - do those double quotes actually exist in your input or are you adding them in this posting? Oh what the heck, I just posted an answer for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do with awk:

```
$ echo 'abc,"xxx,yyy,zzz",abh,abr,alk' | awk -F'"' '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if (i %2 == 0) {
        printf "\""$i"\"";
      } else {
        n=split($i,array,",");
        for (j=1; j<n; j++) {
          print array[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }'
abc
"xxx,yyy,zzz"
abh
abr
alk
```

This does give empty lines though :(, I'm still trying to find out why.

*Update: Fixed + indented*

Comment: +1 for getting close. You're getting blank lines because of ","s before/after the double quotes and so at the start/end of fields. Also, you need to do with split() if i%2 is true, not if it's false.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need to loop at all for the first example:

```bsh
$ awk '{print}' RS=',' <<< 'abc,abd,abf,abz,abz'
abc
abd
abf
abz
abz
```

For the second example you really want a proper CSV parser. Here is a `python` solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from csv import reader, writer
from sys import stdin, stdout
writer(stdout, delimiter='\n').writerows(reader(stdin))
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ cat file
abc,"abd,abf,abz",abh,abr,alk

$ csv_delimiter.py < file 
abc
abd,abf,abz
abh
abr
alk
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first/last double quotes you show in your sample input are actually not present in your input then:

```
$ echo 'abc,"abd,abf,abz",abh,abr,alk' |
awk -F\" '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (i%2) {
            gsub(/^,|,$/,"",$i)
            nf = split($i,a,/,/)
            for (j=1; j<=nf; j++) {
                print a[j]
            }
        }
        else {
            print $i
        }
    }
}'
abc
abd,abf,abz
abh
abr
alk
```

If they are present then:

```
$ echo '"abc,"abd,abf,abz",abh,abr,alk"' |
awk -F\" '{
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        if ( !(i%2) ) {
            gsub(/^,|,$/,"",$i)
            nf = split($i,a,/,/)
            for (j=1; j<=nf; j++) {
                print a[j]
            }
        }
        else {
            print $i
        }
    }
}'
abc
abd,abf,abz
abh
abr
alk
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `csvtool` program that enables you to manipulate CSV files.

It can be installed with `apt-get`  (or with  whatever your package manager is) and used in your Bash files to work with CSV files.